How to write a while loop that iterates through a range until break condition is met
I'm trying to recreate deathrolling from WoW.
Deathrolling in a nutshell:

Two players agree upon an amount of gold to bet.
The first player types '/roll [x]', where [x] can be any upper range (1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, etc.)
The game displays a randomly generated number [y] out of [x] range.
The second player types '/roll [y]'
This process loops until a player rolls 1; the player who rolls 1 loses the bet.


user_A = int(input())

x = random.randrange(1, user_A)
print(x)

user_B = random.randrange(1, x)
print(user_B)


The goal is use a while loop to take what the last user rolled and use it for the next roll. I need help understanding the logic for a while loop that takes input from the user and then automates a random number generator between a given range, until reaching 1, which exits the loop.

right now, you're showing some general requirements and the start of your work, along with a request for general feedback/advice. this is off-topic, as it's open-ended and opinion-based (there really is no single "right" way to build an app). Please read [ask], and then edit to provide a [mcve] with a specific question, along with all relevant details (including data, expected vs actual behavior, errors, etc)

okay, thank you, will edit.

So you're saying that while nobody has rolled a 1, the current_player switches to the other player, who makes a roll in the range of the last_roll which becomes the new last_roll and the process repeats? Once the last_roll is a 1,  the repeating part ends and the current_player loses?

@Grismar yes! this is exactly the process I was trying to explain but couldn't put into words, thank you!

@DavidMakogon I just edited the original post, hopefully it's more concise.

Keep in mind that people aren't asking you to provide less code, but rather more - enough to demonstrate what the problem is, and what you tried and what you need help with. StackOverflow isn't here to write your code for you, but if you have trouble getting something to work that you think should work, share the code and you should get an answer that helps. Have a look at the links @DavidMakogon shared.

I hope I have understood your idea correctly:
import random

class Deathroll:
    def __init__(self, bet):
        self.bet = bet
        self.current_max = None

    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.current_max)

    def play(self):
        print(f" Deathroll game started with a bet of {self.bet} gold! ")

        # First player sets the initial roll range
        self.current_max = int(input("Player 1, enter the upper range for your roll: "))

        current_player = 1
        while True:
            roll_result = self.roll()
            print(f" Player {current_player} rolled: {roll_result}")

            if roll_result == 1:
                print(f" Player {current_player} rolled 1 and loses the bet! ")
                print(f" Player {2 if current_player == 1 else 1} wins {self.bet} gold! ")
                break

            self.current_max = roll_result
            current_player = 3 - current_player

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bet_amount = int(input("Enter the bet amount in gold:  "))
    game = Deathroll(bet_amount)
    game.play()

Example game:
 Deathroll game started with a bet of 150 gold! 
 Player 1 rolled: 145
 Player 2 rolled: 39
 Player 1 rolled: 15
 Player 2 rolled: 4
 Player 1 rolled: 2
 Player 2 rolled: 1
 Player 2 rolled 1 and loses the bet! 
 Player 1 wins 150 gold! 


This is a working solution for the overall problem OP is supposed to solve. But just providing a novel answer to a problem that doesn't really solve a problem is not what StackOverflow is for. This doesn't even align with what OP has been trying so far, nor does it explain why it is better (if it is).

Yup - this is your own solution. It doesn't answer anything specific - it's just you solving a challenge that the OP has not solved. See Why is "can someone help me?" not a useful question? and How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? to better understand why the OP's question is off-topic, and why you shouldn't just post your own custom solution.
